# How to synchronize text in Excel in multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have Excel file with four sheets.

How to make duplication using Excel built-in function using specific parameters?

*Example:*

Sheet 1 - Total:

```
         A            B          C
1    Iveco         100          4.5
2    Jaguar        200          2.3
3    Iveco         150          1.0
4    Skoda         300          1.0
```

Sheet 2 - Iveco:

```
      A            B
1    100          4.5
2    150          1.0
```

Sheet 3 - Jaguar:

```
      A            B
1    200          2.3
```

Sheet 4 - Skoda:

```
      A            B
1    300         1.0
```

So if I wrote at cell **A5** in **Sheet 1 - Total** value **"Iveco"**, automatically wrote values from cells **B5**, **C5** to the **Sheet 2 - Iveco**, cells **A3**, **B3**.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

My VLOOKUP in **Sheet 2 - Iveco**:

```
=VLOOKUP(Total!A1,Total!A1:H200,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a formula that should work for you that I've used in similar situations.

Use this formula in your non-Total sheets.  It'll grab the sheet name, and look for that in your Total sheet, then return the column B (or whatever you put in the `Index()`) info. without repeating:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Total!B$1:B$4,SMALL(IF(Total!A$1:A$4=MID(CELL("filename",$A$3),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),ROW(Total!B$1:B$4)-ROW(Total!B$1)+1),ROWS(Total!B$1:B1))),"")`

The range `Total!B1:B4` should be the range of data you want to return.
`Total!A1:A4`is the list of sheet names.

Enter this with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

Comment: OK I test tomorrow, because is too late in my country. :-)